# Why should a REST service support multiple formats (e.g. XML and JSON)?

Tags: rest

Several sources (e.g. [here](http://blog.octo.com/en/design-a-rest-api/)) suggest that a REST service should support several formats.

What are the benefits of this approach?

Wouldn't it just make a service more complicated and harder to support while providing no additional benefits for a customer?

Comment: can you add links to those sources?

Comment: Added a link to the last source where I found this advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My point of view I hope it is not necessary. If you have given both, you are giving flexibility customer to use either XML or JSON.

I would prefer using JSON hence it is more compact and readable - in communication it will be "faster" simply because less data is transferred than XML. If you use XML, customer can use xslt, xpath things. Both has pros and cons.

Comment: When data are gzipped the size of both XML and JSON payloads is very similar.